# how to increase the size of the color picker and remove its shadow area and show only colorpicker

Tags: swiftui, color-picker

I want to increase the size of the color picker but when I gave the `.scalesize(x:,y:)` it works but my problem is how to remove its outer area so only color picker is shown[the picker color is blue and outer area is gray color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LLoT.png)

```
ColorPicker("",selection: $color.selectedColor)
     .scaleEffect(x:4,y:10)
```

I tried and could increase the color picker size, but how do I remove its outer area and only show the color picker?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The stock `ColorPicker` does not have that level of customization. If you want to change it that much, you will have to create your own picker view. There are many examples on the web that predate the stock `ColorPicker`